# Gas / Gas mixture dynamic viscosity temperature and pressure dependance

Tags: gas-laws, mixtures, viscosity

I’m trying to get an accurate interpretation of certain gases ($CO_2$, $N_2$, $NO$, etc.) dynamic viscosity [Pa.s] as a function of temperature and pressure (afterwards determine the dynamic viscosity of the whole gas mixture).

I have found more than one equation and I’m struggling to choose a proper one which can be interpreted in *MS Excel*. For example, it’s not that easy to find all the coefficient for each equation (unfortunately, same goes for the gas mixture dynamic viscosity: there is *Sutherland-Thiesen* (found on the internet), *Herning–Zipperer* (found in the literature) equation, etc. …).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, Chapter 1.  If the gases and mixtures can be approximated as ideal gases, then their viscosities are independent of pressure.

Comment: @ChetMiller Thanks, I'll look at it. Overall, do you know anything "Excel" based that would allow to define equation as $\eta = f(T,p)$?

Comment: @ChetMiller I have one more question, I have calculated all the substances dynamic viscosity using Lennard-Jones parameters from the book you've suggested, but what if the gas mixture contains water vapour $\rightarrow$ related to the moist gas: $H_2O$: 10 % vol. The book says that calculating water viscosity (I suppose $H_2O$ can't be considered gas even in the form vapour mixture, because 10% vol. is just a water) at different temperature gives not very accurate viscosity estimation. Do you have any suggestions, please? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  What does "because 10% vol. is just a water" mean?  Are you dealing with an ideal gas mixture?  What is the pressure?

Comment: @ChetMiller No, it's exhaust gas mixture: contains $CO_2, O_2, CO, NO, SO_2, N_2$ and $H_2O$. The content of H2O in the mixture is 10% vol. I have computed the viscosities of the gases using the Lennard-Jones parameters, but they can't be used for $H_2O$ the other chapter shows how to calculate viscosity of water, but says it's not very accurate. The pressure changes, that's why I need to make $\eta = f(T,p)$ - pressure ranging from 100 kPa to 300 kPa.

Comment: That's a pretty low pressure.  I would still treat that as an ideal gas, and neglect the pressure dependence.  If the water is only 10% by volume, it can't have much of an effect on the viscosity of the mixture.  I would use the results in the other chapter to get the viscosity of  pure water for applying the mixture rule.  Understand that, in the end, this is not going to give you a super-accurate estimate of the mixture viscosity, but it is about the best you're going to do.

Comment: @ChetMiller OK, I see. Thanks, I'll do as you say if the difference is negligible (I have been also struggling finding a proper formula to calculate water density as a function of pressure and temperature: $\rho_{H_2O} = f(p,T)$. I guess that simple equation of state won't do the trick...) I can use the problem 1A.4: Estimation of liquid viscosity as an example. What exactly do you mean by the mixture rule? I thought it's sum of each substance's viscosity multiplied by their content in the mixture. Thanks for your help (Please, note that I'm not chemist, so some of questions may seem stupid)!